# Without for loop in R

Tags: r

I have a vector, which may sometimes contain 0 and 1.

I want to need to put this vector into the function qnorm

```
qnorm(vec , 0, 1)
```

However, the 0 and  1 s in `vec` may cause `qnorm` to produce `-inf` or `inf`. Now the following for loop is what I want to do to process the vector `vec` first, and then put the vector in `qnorm` function. However, I want to avoid using the for loop and the which function. Is there a more elegant solution to this ?

```
for(i in 1:length(vec)) {
    if(vec[i] == 0) {vec[i] <- vec[i] + 1e-50}
    else if(vec[i] == 1) {vec[i] <- vec[i] - 1e-50  }
}
```

Comment: You've now conflated true zeroes with true 1e-50 values, and true ones with true 1-1e-50 values. Can't you leave the infinities alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ifelse`:

```
vec <- ifelse(vec == 0, vec + 1e-50, vec - 1e-50)
```

If your vector contains other values than 0 and 1 you may want to use:

```
vec[vec == 0] <- vec[vec == 0] + 1e-50
vec[vec == 1] <- vec[vec == 1] - 1e-50
```

Comment: does ur answer take into account the case , where if `vec[i] == 1`, then do `vec[i] <- vec[i] - 1e-50`    ? I only want to modify the vector if I see 0 and 1 s in it.

Comment: @Chinegro: No, sorry I didn't read your question carefully enough. Please see my edit.

Comment: You could also use `pmin` and `pmax`